# How to convert Dataset into JavaPairRDD?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, java-pair-rdd

There are methods to convert Dataset to JavaRDD .

```
Dataset<Row> dataFrame;
JavaRDD<String> data = dataFrame.toJavaRDD();
```

Is there any other ways to convert Dataset into `javaPairRDD<Long, Vector>`?

Comment: Can you post value of  dataFrame.printSchema();

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `PairFunction` like below. Please check the index of element in your Dataset. In below sample index 0 has long value and index 3 has Vector.

```
JavaPairRDD<Long, Vector> jpRDD = dataFrame.toJavaRDD().mapToPair(new PairFunction<Row, Long, Vector>() {
    public Tuple2<Long, Vector> call(Row row) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple2<Long, Vector>((Long) row.get(0), (Vector) row.get(3));
    }
});
```